# calculating number of days

Tags: javascript, html

The javascript code doesn't run. Can't seem to find any error in the code. Has to be some minor error. I have checked the logic from the osts on the same here.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>
        function finddays()
        {
            var today = new Date();
            var user = new Date(myform.year.value,myform.month.value,myform.day.value,0,0,0,0);
            var msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            var daysLeft = Math.abs((user.getTime() - today.getTime())/msPerDay);
            daysLeft = Math.round(daysLeft);
            retun(daysLeft);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myform">
            <input type="number" name="date" value="date" min="1" max="31">
            <input type="number" name="month" value="month" min="1" max="12">
            <input type="number" name="year" value="year" min="1980" max="2200">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="windows.alert ('Number of days: '+ finddays())">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a typo  -```return(daysLeft)```

Comment: Also, just to let you know in an ideal JS world you should call your function ```findDays()``` This is because Javascript uses camelcasing as its standard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789656/why-use-camelcase-in-javascript

Comment: Next time try to use tools like Findbugs or Chrome Developer tools. The Javascript console should tell you what @Paul-fiztgerald noted

Comment: One more thing. It is not `windows.alert`. It is `window.alert`. I wonder how you didn't get any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Riya Tilwani
You are missing following things:

You have the html element name **date** but you have tried retrieving it using **day**. Please change it to the following:

```
new Date(myform.year.value,myform.month.value,myform.date.value,0,0,0,0)
```

You have a syntax error at **retun(daysLeft)**. Please change it to following:

```
return(daysLeft);
```

In HTML while onclick function you have used **windows.alert**. Instead use the following

```
window.alert
```

Also the time that you are calculating is not exact because **month is taken as index starting from 0**. So use the following (decrease the month by 1):

```
var user = new Date(myform.year.value,myform.month.value-1,myform.date.value,0,0,0,0);
```

I have tested the code, it works fine if you make the above changes.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, Just copy paste the complete code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>
        function finddays()
        {
            var today = new Date();
            var user = new Date(myform.year.value,myform.month.value,myform.date.value,0,0,0,0);
            var msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            var daysLeft = Math.abs((user.getTime() - today.getTime())/msPerDay);
            daysLeft = Math.round(daysLeft);
            alert('Number of days: '+daysLeft);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myform">
            <input type="number" name="date" value="date" min="1" max="31">
            <input type="number" name="month" value="month" min="1" max="12">
            <input type="number" name="year" value="year" min="1980" max="2200">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="finddays();">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two mistakes:

1) Using `myform` without declaring it

2) Using Submit Button instead of button.

Please change your code to below :

**HTML** :

```
<form name="myform" id="myform">
    <input type="number" name="date" value="date" min="1" max="31"/>
    <input type="number" name="month" value="month" min="1" max="12"/>
    <input type="number" name="year" value="year" min="1980" max="2200"/>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="finddays();"/>
</form>
```

**Javascript** :

```
function finddays()
{ 
    var myform=document.getElementById("myform");
    var today = new Date();

    var user = new Date(myform.year.value,myform.month.value,myform.date.value,0,0,0,0);
    var msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var daysLeft = Math.abs((user.getTime() - today.getTime())/msPerDay);
    daysLeft = Math.round(daysLeft);
    alert('Number of days: '+daysLeft);
}
```

**[Check out JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qk2gh0v/1/)**